# How would I go about finding an alternative to obtaining a static pointer address?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cheat-engine

After each restart, the pointer I find has changed to a new address. I've been using cheat engine. I can reliably find the pointer again but it's never in the same address. The code that accesses the address (among 100's of other things) is:

```
mov rdi, [rax + r13*8 + 28]
```

I recently learned about AoB injection and searching more info about it has led me here. I found a similar question that was about dll injection but it was never answered online. I have a feeling that if I can maybe find a way to find out the value of RAX and R13 on each instance of the game or when it changes after a death, I can find the address I need that leads to the value I'm looking for. Am I on the right track? Any insight and advice would be greatly appreciated. I don't actually have a background in any of this stuff (computer languages?) but I'm kind of really getting into this.

Comment: I hate cheaters. I think asking for help on how to cheat disclaiming " I don't actually have a background in any of this stuff (computer languages?)" is lame. Not only you are bad at the game, or worse, willing to profit from kids trying to have fun, but you don't even consider the topic and the knowledge of it relevant enough to deserve being studied.

Comment: Disable ASLR so the addresses are the same each time.

Comment: I apologize, I thought this was a forum I could ask questions about this topic. This is for personal use and this is a single player game without online capabilities (it's a VERY old game remade, probably your age at least) so I don't understand the assumptions being made.

Comment: @littlebear Your question is definitely on topic.

Comment: So I've managed to inject a code that will disable damage being done to the player, because the same code also applied to the computer, by comparing a register at the time of the subtraction of the value of rax. In case anyone ever tries to look for the answer to my question. Thanks anyone and everyone for their input.